# Добавление записи в MySQL через html-форму

Tags: php, html, mysql

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь выучить язык `PHP`. Затормозил на добавлении записи в `MySQL`  через `html`-форму.

Есть `html`-форма:

```
<html>
<body>
<form aсtion="/connect.php" method="post">
</br></br><input type="button" name="Pоle1" value="Поле 1"/>
</br></br><input type="button" name="Pole2" value="Поле 2"/>
</br></br><input type="button" name="Pole3" value="Поле 3"/>
</br></br><input type="button" name="Pole4" value="Поле 4"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Есть connect.php:

```
<?php
$Pole1   = trim ( $Pole1 ); 
$Pole2   = trim ( $Pole2 ); 
$Pole3   = trim ( $Pole3 );
$Pole4   = trim ( $Pole4 );  
$Pole1   = addslashes ( $Pole1 ); 
$Pole2   = addslashes ( $Pole2 );  
$Pole3   = addslashes ( $Pole3 ); 
$Pole4   = addslashes ( $Pole4 );

$connect=mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
if ( !$connect ) die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");
$db="edu";
mysql_select_db ( $db ) or die ("Невозможно открыть $db");
$query = "INSERT INTO dannye VALUES ('"
         .$Pole1."', '".$Pole2."', '".$Pole3."', '"
         .$Pole4."')";
$result = mysql_query ( $query );
if ($result) echo "Добавлено в базу данных.";
mysql_close ( $connect);
?>
```

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку записываллись данные в базу. То есть, если нажата кнопка "Поле 1", то в базу `db` таблицу `dannye` в поле `Pole1` добавлялась запись и так далее до кнопки "Поле 4". Но этого не происходит.

Answer (score 2):

Код должен выглядеть таким образом, а не как предлагает [@Rules](/users/1267/rules)

```
mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","") or die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");
mysql_select_db("edu") or die ("Невозможно открыть таблицу с данными");

$Pole1   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole1']) );
$Pole2   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole2']) );
$Pole3   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole3']) );
$Pole4   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole4']) );

$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO dannye VALUES ('".$Pole1."', '".$Pole2."', '".$Pole3."', '".$Pole4."')");

if ($result) 
  echo "Добавлено в базу данных.";

mysql_close ($connect);
```

А насчёт вашего вопроса, получается, что вы хотите чтобы из одной формы заносилось только значение от нажатой кнопки.

Если это будут не кнопки а текстовые поля, то возможно так

```
<form aсtion="/connect.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="Pоle[]" value="Поле 1"/><br>
<input type="text" name="Pole[]" value=""/><br>
<input type="text" name="Pole[]" value=""/><br>
<input type="text" name="Pole[]" value=""/>
</form>
```

-- connect.php

```
mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","") or die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");
mysql_select_db("edu") or die ("Невозможно открыть таблицу с данными");

foreach($_POST['Pole'] as $key=>$value){ //$key содержит цифру от 0 до n-1 полей

  $value= trim($value);

  if(!empty($value)){
    $value= addslashes($value);
    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO dannye ('Pole".($key+1)."') VALUES ('".$value."')");
    if ($result) echo "В БД было добавлена строка с одним заполненным полем - Pole".($key+1);
  }

}

mysql_close ($connect);
```

Но в этом случаем, заполнив сразу несколько полей получаем сразу несколько новых записей с разбросом значений по полям.

Или уж каждой кнопке новая форма

```
<form aсtion="/connect.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="Pоle1" value="Поле 1"/>
</form><br>
<form aсtion="/connect.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="Pole2" value="Поле 2"/>
</form><br>
<form aсtion="/connect.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="Pole3" value="Поле 3"/>
</form><br>
<form aсtion="/connect.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="Pole4" value="Поле 4"/>
</form>
```

-- connect.php

```
if(isset($_POST['Pole1'])){
  $Name = 'Pole1';
  $Pole   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole1']) );

}else if(isset($_POST['Pole2'])){
  $Name = 'Pole2';
  $Pole   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole2']) );

}else if(isset($_POST['Pole3'])){
  $Name = 'Pole3';
  $Pole   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole3']) );

}else if(isset($_POST['Pole4'])){
  $Name = 'Pole4';
  $Pole   = addslashes( trim($_POST['Pole4']) );

}

if(isset($Name)){
  mysql_pconnect("localhost","root","") or die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");
  mysql_select_db("edu") or die ("Невозможно открыть таблицу с данными");

  $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO dannye ('".$Name."') VALUES ('".$Pole."')");
  if ($result)
    echo 'Ты нажал на кнопку '.$Pole.' теперь в базе, в этом поле, сможешь найти запись, со значением "'.$Pole.'"';
  mysql_close ($connect);
}
```

Вообще не копай в эту сторону. Отправка кнопок разве где то понадобится? легче ссылки сделать.

Лучше поизучать PDO (из серии работы с базами данных), как лучше фильтровать пришедшие данные, к примеру, я бы использовал  filter_input
И поучить HTML / XHTML  - тег br пишется явно не так как ты написал, а чтобы отправить форму используется тип submit

Comment: И таким образом код выглядеть не должен. Возможны sql-инъекции :)

Answer (score 0):

`$Pole1` поменяй на `$_POST['Pole1']` и так все остальные

Comment: Извините, но где конкретно произвести эту замену?

Comment: Вот здесь :
**
<?php
$Pole1   = trim ( $Pole1 );//здесь надо как сказал @johniek
$Pole2   = trim ( $Pole2 ); //здесь надо как сказал @johniek
........................... //здесь надо как сказал @johniek
$Pole4   = addslashes ( $Pole4 );//здесь надо как сказал @johniek
**

Comment: То есть вот так?


$Pole1   = $_POST['Pole1'];

Или 

$_POST['Pole1']  = trim($_POST['Pole1']);

Или 

$_POST['Pole1'] = trim ( $Pole1 );

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно скал [[@johniek_comp](/users/5557/johniek_comp)](/users/5557/johniek_comp):

```
<?php
$Pole1   = trim ( $_POST['Pole1'] ); 
$Pole2   = trim ( $_POST['Pole2'] );
$Pole3   = trim ( $_POST['Pole3'] );
$Pole4   = trim ( $_POST['Pole4'] );  
$Pole1   = addslashes ( $_POST['$Pole1'] ); 
$Pole2   = addslashes ( $_POST['$Pole2'] );   
$Pole3   = addslashes ( $_POST['$Pole3'] ); 
$Pole4   = addslashes ( $_POST['$Pole4'] );

$connect=mysql_pconnect ("localhost","root","");
if ( !$connect ) die ("Невозможно подключение к MySQL");
$db="edu";
mysql_select_db ( $db ) or die ("Невозможно открыть $db");
$query = "INSERT INTO dannye VALUES ('"
         .$Pole1."', '".$Pole2."', '".$Pole3."', '"
         .$Pole4."')";
$result = mysql_query ( $query );
if ($result) echo "Добавлено в базу данных.";
mysql_close ( $connect);
?>
```